# Roblox : Gui Pulling a Houdini

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I am trying to make a gui element which detects changes in the currency and displays the changes as text (E.X '+10' '-1') but instead of updating the gui just disappears. Please help.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local leaderstats = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
local moneyValue = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Money")

local guiElement = script.Parent

local display = guiElement:FindFirstChild("TextBox")
while not display do
    wait()
    display = guiElement:FindFirstChild("TextBox")
end

moneyValue.Changed:Connect(function(newMoney)
    local change = newMoney - moneyValue.Value
    moneyValue.Value = newMoney

    if change > 0 then
        display.Text = "+" .. tostring(change)
        display.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0) -- Set text color to green
    elseif change < 0 then
        display.Text = tostring(change)
        display.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0) -- Set text color to red
    else
        display.Text = ""
        display.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255) -- Reset text color to white
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure because the information you provided does not appear satisfactory to me, but then again maybe I am wrong.

**What if you make sure that the visibility is always set to True? Maybe you turned it off in order for you to see in the Studio when moving around and forgot to set visibility or active to True?**

Pardon my rustiness when it comes to lua.

Edit: Also the title is quite intreguing, made me laugh :)

Comment: Yeah the visibility is true always as far as I know, should this script be a local script tho?

Comment: Did you solve it? Yeah I am pretty sure GUI goes from local script because it is clientsided.